# Secure and insecure connection over the same socket

Tags: cocoa, sockets, ssl

I have some Python code I'm trying to translate to Obj-C/Cocoa.  It requires a network connection; the initialization string is sent in plaintext then the connection is secured.
Basically, it works like this:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host,port))
sock.send( ... )
sock.recv( ... )
sslSock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
sslSock.send( ... )
sslSock.recv( ...)
```

So far, I have the following.  First I create the socket connection and the R/W streams:

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)HOST, PORT, &readStream, &writeStream);

inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

When the `NSStreamEventOpenCompleted` is sent, I store the native socket handle:

```
NSSocketNativeHandle *socketHandle = [[outputStream propertyForKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle] bytes];
```

I handle the `NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` and `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable` events, as appropriate.  Then create two new streams from the stored socket handle, and set the SSL properties:

```
[inputStream close];
[outputStream close];
[inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault, *socketHandle, &readStream, &writeStream);

inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv3 forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];

outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv3 forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

And this is as far as I get.  The `NSStreamEventOpenCompleted` event is called on both of the new streams, but `NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` and `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`  events are never raised.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like my problem was two-fold.

1. When creating a connection via `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost`, the `kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket` property is set to TRUE automatically.  It should be FALSE.

   ```
   CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)HOST, PORT, &readStream, &writeStream);
   inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
   [inputStream setDelegate:self];
   [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
   [inputStream setProperty:(id)kCFBooleanFalse forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket];
   ```
2. I wasn't setting up SSL correctly.

   ```
   NSMutableDictionary *sslSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   [sslSettings setObject:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLLevel];
   [sslSettings setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot];
   [sslSettings setObject:HOST forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
   [inputStream setProperty:sslSettings forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings];
   [inputStream open];
   ```

Comment: Hi, sorry to bring up old question again but I have the same problem. I need to do something with socket and then upgrade it to secure. I've tried the method you've described but I still do not receive NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable events. I even tried just recreate streams without any security upgrade but it is still the same. I am running iOS 6 on iPad. Does your code still works? Or maybe you have made some improvements?